# Bash not found in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, containers, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have an issue with Jenkins not recognizing bash.

I run a `stage` with docker `agent` using a golang image. When trying to run an sh file, I receive this error:

> + ./build/docker/docker.sh
>   /home/jenkins/workspace/003-CGI-App-setup-ACS-build-4ZEA3UO3JRWIGZRIGIBD7BRQJV7JJ4LAKTS4XDXT6N3GDVU7Z4WA@tmp/durable-46264c73/script.sh: line 1: ./build/docker/docker.sh: not found

**This is my stage:**

```
stage('Build & publish') {
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'golang:1.10-alpine3.7'
            }
        }
        steps {
            checkout scm
            unstash 'war'
            sh 'export PATH=/bin/bash:$PATH'
            sh 'cp XXX/XXX/target/*.war build/docker/ROOT.war'
            sh 'chmod 777 ./build/docker/docker.sh'
            sh 'go build -o XXX'
            sh './XXX build'
            sh './build/docker/docker.sh'
        }
    }
```

My docker.sh file starts with `#!/bin/bash` as well.

**Does anyone know if it's related to the docker image? If yes, am I adding bash correctly?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Many lighter-weight Docker images, especially those built on top of Alpine Linux, don't contain GNU Bash.

The best solution here is to rewrite your script to not specifically require bash.  Change its shebang line to `#!/bin/sh`, and limit its syntax to what's allowed in the [POSIX shell specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18).  This is more than sufficient for most straightforward "do A, B, C, and then D" style scripts; if you find yourself reaching for bash-specific features like arrays, consider a more powerful scripting language like Python.

Specifically in the single line

```
sh 'export PATH=/bin/bash:$PATH'
```

- Each `sh` command runs in its own execution environment with a clean environment, so environment variable settings from an earlier `sh` statement don't affect a later one; this statement is a no-op.
- Elements of `$PATH` are directories, not individual files.
- `/bin` is all but required to be on `$PATH` and it is in all standard execution environments.  (If `/bin/bash` exists, then explicit `bash -c '...'` commands and `#!/bin/bash` shebang lines will find it.)

(The other frequent cause of problems like this is mixed Windows/Linux environments where the actual shebang line ends with a DOS-style CR/LF two-character newline and the environment can't run `/bin/bash\r`.)

Comment: Even though all the information in this answer is correct, it is actually not the root cause of his problem, since it stems from a Jenkins issue and not a Docker issue. The real problem here is that he is trying to access a `./build/docker/docker.sh` in his Jenkins workspace, which does not exist because it is not in the Docker image for whatever reason.

Comment: If it's checked into the source code repository, then the `checkout scm` step should make it available?  But yes, this is an important point.

Comment: Yeah, if it is checked into SCM it should be getting put into the workspace. However, the specific information for `checkout([$class: 'GitSCM'...])` or similar seems to be absent from the `Jenkinsfile` (just pseudo-code). There seem to be specifics absent here from the question. On the other hand, if the `sh` was absent then `chmod` would be failing, so now I am more inclined to agree with your answer.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers.

I could solve the issue by stashing built files and running the script in a separated stage.

I found out that the docker image doesn't allow to use bash.